# How to handle null values when we are doing sorting in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-order-by, sql-server-2012

I am trying to get sorting with  order by column with null values in columns by using the below query like passing parameters to the store procedure along with  sort direction and sort by column as input parameters

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[tp_SelectTransactionHistorySearch]
(
   @OffSetRowNo INT,     
   @FetchRowNo INT,
   @StatusSelection NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @IsReviewed Bit,
   @ProjectCaseNumber VARCHAR(MAX),
   @CostPageNumber VARCHAR(MAX),
   @TransactionTypeChange VARCHAR(MAX),
   @DescriptionChange VARCHAR(MAX),
   @TrasactionCreateOnBeginDate DATE,
   @TransactionCreatedOnEndDate DATE,
   @TransactionUpdatedOnBeginDate DATE,
   @TransactionUpdateOnEndDate DATE,
   @ItemID VARCHAR(MAX),
   @SortOrder VARCHAR(MAX),
   @SortByColumnName VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS

  SELECT 
        TransactionID,IsReviewed,ItemID,CostPageNumber,Comments,
        CreatedBy,CreatedDateTime,UpdatedBy,UpdatedDateTime,
        TransactionDescription,TransactionTypeID,PROJCASE,
        TransactionStatusID, TransactionStatusTypeName,
        TransactionStatusTypeDescription,    
        TransactionTypeName, TransactionTypeDescription,
        COUNT(*) OVER () as TotalCount
 FROM
 ( //select
  //  union
  //  select
  //  union  
   //like select statement from union results
 ) ResultSet
      //here i am doing sorting 
     ORDER BY
 CASE @SortOrder 
    WHEN 'ASC' THEN  
       CASE @SortByColumnName
         WHEN 'TransactionID' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ResultSet.TransactionID)
         WHEN 'ItemID' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ResultSet.ItemID)
         WHEN 'CostPageNumber' THEN ResultSet.CostPageNumber
         WHEN 'Comments' THEN ResultSet.Comments
         WHEN 'CreatedBy' THEN ResultSet.CreatedBy
         WHEN 'CreatedDateTime' THEN  CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ResultSet.CreatedDateTime)
         WHEN 'UpdatedBy' THEN ResultSet.UpdatedBy
         WHEN 'UpdatedDateTime' THEN  CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ResultSet.UpdatedDateTime)
         WHEN 'TransactionDescription' THEN ResultSet.TransactionDescription
         WHEN 'TransactionTypeName' THEN ResultSet.TransactionTypeName
         WHEN 'PROJCASE' THEN ResultSet.PROJCASE
         WHEN 'TransactionStatusTypeName' THEN ResultSet.TransactionStatusTypeName
         WHEN 'TransactionStatusTypeDescription' THEN ResultSet.TransactionStatusTypeDescription
       END 
  END 
  ASC, 
 CASE @SortOrder 
    WHEN 'DESC' THEN              
       CASE @SortByColumnName
         WHEN 'TransactionID' THEN  CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ResultSet.TransactionID)
         WHEN 'ItemID' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ResultSet.ItemID)
         WHEN 'CostPageNumber' THEN ResultSet.CostPageNumber
         WHEN 'Comments' THEN ResultSet.Comments
         WHEN 'CreatedBy' THEN ResultSet.CreatedBy
         WHEN 'CreatedDateTime' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ResultSet.CreatedDateTime)
         WHEN 'UpdatedBy' THEN ResultSet.UpdatedBy
         WHEN 'UpdatedDateTime' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ResultSet.UpdatedDateTime)
         WHEN 'TransactionDescription' THEN ResultSet.TransactionDescription
         WHEN 'TransactionTypeName' THEN ResultSet.TransactionTypeName
         WHEN 'PROJCASE' THEN ResultSet.PROJCASE
         WHEN 'TransactionStatusTypeName' THEN ResultSet.TransactionStatusTypeName
         WHEN 'TransactionStatusTypeDescription' THEN ResultSet.TransactionStatusTypeDescription
       END 
 END 
 OFFSET ( @OffSetRowNo-1 ) * @FetchRowNo ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @FetchRowNo ROWS ONLY
```

here without using any orderBy(sorting methods) i am getting `two rows` as results even if they are null values in columns but with sorting (i.e) OrderBy I am able to get only one row as result 
and i am not sure how to handle the null values when using order by , but I have tried below statement

```
  WHEN ColumnB IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC,
```

but when apply this one  i am getting syntax errors....
would any pls suggest any ideas how to handle null values when order by at this situation..
I am using sql server 2012 Edition

Many thanks In advance ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplified scenario is given below for dynamic sort order and sort field.

```
--TEST DATA
DECLARE @MYTable TABLE (EmpID INT, EmpName VARCHAR(10) , JoinDate DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @MYTable VALUES (1,'E1','1/1/2001');
INSERT INTO @MYTable VALUES (2,'E2','2/2/2002');
INSERT INTO @MYTable VALUES (3,'E3','5/5/2001');

--INPUT Parameters
DECLARE @SortParam VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SortParam = 'JoinDate'

DECLARE @SortDirection VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SortDirection = 'DESC'


--@RankTypeID Variable
DECLARE @RankTypeID  INT

--EMPNAME
IF (@SortParam = 'EmpName' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC')
BEGIN 
    SET @RankTypeID = 1 
END

IF (@SortParam = 'EmpName' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC')
BEGIN
    SET @RankTypeID = -1    
END

--EmpID
IF (@SortParam = 'EmpID' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC')
BEGIN 
    SET @RankTypeID = 2 
END

IF (@SortParam = 'EmpID' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC')
BEGIN
    SET @RankTypeID = -2
END

--JoinDate
IF (@SortParam = 'JoinDate' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC')
BEGIN 
    SET @RankTypeID = 3 
END

IF (@SortParam = 'JoinDate' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC')
BEGIN
    SET @RankTypeID = -3
END


-- SELECT
SELECT * 
FROM @MYTable M
ORDER BY 
        CASE @RankTypeID WHEN 1 then EmpName ELSE null end ASC,
        CASE @RankTypeID WHEN -1 then EmpName ELSE null end DESC,

        CASE @RankTypeID WHEN 2 then [EmpID] else null end ASC ,
        CASE @RankTypeID WHEN -2 then [EmpID] else null end DESC ,

        CASE @RankTypeID WHEN 3 then JoinDate else null end  ASC,
        CASE @RankTypeID WHEN -3 then JoinDate else null end  DESC


--END
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the builtin [`ISNULL()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)-function?

```
ISNULL(ColumnB, 1)
```